# opencv_core242 not found in visual studio 2017 with opencv 3.3.2

Tags: opencv

I use visual studio 2017 and the newest opencv 3.3.2 and I installed Emgu and add librarys and I still get an error that copencv_core242 is not found if I want to run an example. Do you know whats wrong?

[image]

Comment: change your project dependency properties setting

Comment: what should I change here

Comment: You just put the error info without any project settings, so how can i know.

Answer (score 0):

`opencv_core242.dll` is an OpenCV 2.4.2 lib. You should unlink your example from `opencv_core242` and link it to `opencv_core332` if you have only OpenCV 3.3.2.

Another solution is to install (the very outdated) OpenCV 2.4.2.

Also, don't forget to add the dll folder in system's path.